# venv with renamed python exectuable

Tags: python, python-venv, autodesk, maya-api

I'm trying to create a virtual environment using a custom python build e.g. `mayapy.exe -m venv myVenv` but I keep getting the following error:

`Error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

This is a known issue -> https://bugs.python.org/issue43749 and has something to do with the fact that I'm working with a renamed executable.

Do you guys have any work around for this issue?

Comment: Is this part of some automated process? I would just make a script to rename the `myapy.exe` into `python.exe`, to create the venv and then to rename the `python.exe` back to `myapy.exe`. Other possibility would be to hunt down the bug and help `venv` developers to fix it.

Comment: @np8 sadly renaming the executable won't work. What do you mean by "is this part of some automated process?"

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that if the executable could be renamed temporarily. And that would be only useful, if you need to create virtual environments inside a script or otherwise non-manually.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're in a windows environment, you can try creating a symbolic link at the same location. A symbolic link is like a file system shortcut. Open the Command Shell with Administrator Privileges. Navigate to the location of mayapy.exe from within the shell and type:

```
mklink python.exe mayapy.exe
```

It creates a symbolic link in the file system. If it doesn't work try the /H option.

Comment: For the record, Maya has additional/unique dependencies in their version of Python (mayapy.exe), so creating a virtual environment might be more involved than simply creating symbolic link.